# In React, are there two Virtual DOMs to do the diff'ing?

Tags: reactjs

This is a somewhat advanced question about React:

Since it uses a Virtual DOM because the real DOM is too slow, and the Virtual DOM is used to diff whether something is changed, as to whether to actually re-render it to the real DOM, so then, it seems natural that there are two Virtual DOMs so that the speed is fast for the diff'ing (we don't want to touch the real DOM until the last moment).

So does React have two Virtual DOMs? One for the current state of the DOM, and one for the new change of content for each event cycle, so that the diff'ed results determines whether to actually change the real DOM?  So that means, there are actually 3 DOMs (2 Virtual and one actual) in React.

Comment: Yes, when a change is made a new virtual dom is created and diff'd against the previous DOM and then updated in the most efficient way possible.
Here is a good blog post explaining how it works https://adhithiravi.medium.com/react-virtual-dom-explained-in-simple-english-fc2d0b277bc5